# svg viewBox looks different in vue js

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to understand why my svg viewBox behaves differently in html and in vuejs.

This is my code in vue

```
<template>
 <div class="venuecontainer" style="background-color:#808040;">
    <svg class="bounds" width=95% height=95% 
    viewbox=" 0 0 100 100" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="0.5vmin" fill="white" />
    </svg>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'VenueView'
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

and this in html

```
<div class="venuecontainer" style="background-color:#808040;">
    <svg class="bounds" width=95% height=95% 
    viewbox=" 0 0 100 100" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="0.5vmin" fill="white" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

I actually copy pasted the relevant part, so the are identical.

However html produces the result I expect:
[image]

and the vue code produces this:
[image]

Why??
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

FML.
It's viewBox not viewbox. Only matters in Vue for obvious reasons.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).